# Java Actionlistener submit buttons

Tags: java, swing, while-loop, actionlistener, jtextfield

When I input something into the textbox my application freezes and stops responding if I hit enter. Its a game where you try to gets a number between 1 and 100. I think I need a submit button or an ActionListener on the enter key. Can somebody help me with this. Also is there a way to break lines in FlowLayout? Or is another layout better? Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class game extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Random rand = new Random();
    private int number = rand.nextInt(101);
    private JLabel result, prompt;
    private JTextField input;


    game() {
        super("Numbers");
        setSize(500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        prompt = new JLabel("Enter a number between 1 and 100");
        add(prompt);

        input = new JTextField(3);
        add(input);

        result = new JLabel("");
        add(result);



        event a = new event();
        input.addActionListener(a);

    }

    public class event implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
            int guess = 0;

            try {
                guess = Integer.parseInt(input.getText());
            } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                result.setText("Error - Illegal Data Entered");
                result.setForeground(Color.RED);
            }


            while(guess!=number) {
                if(guess>number) {
                    result.setText("Guess Too High. Try Again.");
                    result.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
                } else if(guess<number) {
                    result.setText("Guess Too Low. Try Again.");
                    result.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
                } else {
                    result.setText("Unknown Error");
                    result.setForeground(Color.RED);
                }
            }
            if(guess==number){
                result.setText("Right the number was "+number);
                result.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new game().setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

## Update

So I removed the While-loop and everything worked OK. Did it do that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here, `guess` or `number` never changes the value, infinite loop

```
 while(guess!=number) {
                    if(guess>number) {
                        result.setText("Guess Too High. Try Again.");
                        result.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
                    } else if(guess<number) {
                        result.setText("Guess Too Low. Try Again.");
                        result.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
                    } else {
                        result.setText("Unknown Error");
                        result.setForeground(Color.RED);
                    }
                }
```

You only have to delete the while, is unnecesary

So ur inner class would be like this

```
public class MyEvent implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
            int guess = 0;

            try {

               guess = Integer.parseInt(input.getText());
                        if(guess>number) {
                            result.setText("Guess Too High. Try Again.");
                            result.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
                        } else if(guess<number) {
                            result.setText("Guess Too Low. Try Again.");
                            result.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
                        } else {
                           result.setText("Right the number was "+number);
                           result.setForeground(Color.GREEN);                      
                        }

            }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
                result.setText("Error - Illegal Data Entered");
                result.setForeground(Color.RED);               
            }

  }
}
```

i try catch all the block cause when that integer fails u have to end ur execution of the event..

**NOTE** Follow conventions, put declarative names and classes should start with UpperCase

Comment: So if I add a `if(guess==number){break;}` will that fix it?

Comment: watch, u have another potential error with the try and catch, if u insert a string execution will going u dont finish ur code execution when catch so i put it at the end of the block

Comment: @Col1107 see what i put before, take care with the try and catch

Answer (score 1):

You're blocking the Event Dispatching Thread with a `while-loop` which can never bee broken...

```
while(guess!=number) {...}
```

**Updated...**

Instead of...

```
while(guess!=number) {
    if(guess>number) {
        result.setText("Guess Too High. Try Again.");
        result.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
    } else if(guess<number) {
        result.setText("Guess Too Low. Try Again.");
        result.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
    } else {
        result.setText("Unknown Error");
        result.setForeground(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

Try

```
if(guess>number) {
    result.setText("Guess Too High. Try Again.");
    result.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
} else if(guess<number) {
    result.setText("Guess Too Low. Try Again.");
    result.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
} else {
    result.setText("Unknown Error");
    result.setForeground(Color.RED);
}
```

Swing is an event driven environment.  That is you program will wait (automatically) until the user does something and your program will respond to it

Comment: Sorry I'm still not very good with Java, how would I fix that?

Comment: Well, that depends on what you want to achieve.  Start by getting rid of it (but keep the code inside it) and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop.  `guess` is never updated in the body of your looping construct, so the condition will always be false every time you iterate.